# how to create a circular route based on given distance and start location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I would like to create a circular route from distance. First, I get current position, and then create a circular route based on the specified distance. But I don't know how to achieve this at all. I couldn't find any helpful methods in Google Maps API.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to draw a Circle on a map, and based on your tags you might want to use the Maps SDK for Android. Here's the documentation for creating Circles on a Google Map for Android. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes

If you want a polygon of exact points on roads based on distance from a center point, you might be looking for an Isodistance. Here is some open source code in JavaScript for building an isodistance polygon. You would use the same strategy in Java to do this in the Maps SDK for Android. https://github.com/dugwood/isochrone-isodistance-with-google-maps